# What is the proper syntax for column BETWEEN two dates?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get between dates

```
SELECT y.*, x.id as customerNumber
FROM table1 y
LEFT JOIN table2 x
    ON x.id = y.id
WHERE y.date_created BETWEEN ('2011-12-06','yyyy-mm-dd') AND  y.date_created('2011-12-07','yyyy-mm-dd');
```

This gives me error

> Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need the ,'yyyy-mm-dd' portion

Comment: Hint: `('2011-12-06', 'yyyy-mm-dd')` is two values...

Answer (score 4):

You are repeating `y.date_created` on the right side of the `BETWEEN`, and passing two string values inside `()` on both sides:

```
 y.date_created between '2011-12-06' AND  '2011-12-07';
```

The date literals in the format `YYYY-mm-dd` are enough on their own.  By passing `('2011-12-06', 'yyyy-mm-dd')` to `BETWEEN`, it is seeing two operands on the left and erroring out. On the right side, you then use `y.date_created()` syntactically like a function, which doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

```
WHERE y.date_created between '2011-12-06' AND '2011-12-07'
```

Simple as that

Note that `between '2011-12-06' AND '2011-12-07'` equals `between '2011-12-06 00:00:00' AND '2011-12-06 23:59:59'`, not `2011-12-07 23:59:59`

Answer (score 0):

In your code:
    y.date_created between ('2011-12-06','yyyy-mm-dd') AND  y.date_created('2011-12-07','yyyy-mm-dd');

I think in between you don't need to repeat the field name again with and phrase:

```
y.date_created between ('2011-12-06','yyyy-mm-dd') AND ('2011-12-07','yyyy-mm-dd');
```